# json.Unmarshall not working properly

Tags: json, go

I am reading a json document from localhost and trying to convert it to a `Test` type:

```
type Test struct {
    one string
    two string
    three string
}

res, err := http.Get("http://localhost/d/")
perror(err)
defer res.Body.Close()
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
perror(err)
var data Test
err = json.Unmarshal(body, &data)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("%T\n%s\n%#v\n",err, err, err)
    switch v := err.(type){
    case *json.SyntaxError:
        fmt.Println(string(body[v.Offset - 40:v.Offset]))
    }
}


fmt.Println("response:")
fmt.Println(string(body))
fmt.Println("type:")
fmt.Println(data)
```

But the output shows an empty object:

```
response:
{
    "one" : "one thing",
    "two" : "two things",
    "three" : "3 things"

}
type:
{  }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens when you make your fields exported? That is.. uppercase first letters? `One`, `Two` and `Three` in the struct?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting Go struct to JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270816/converting-go-struct-to-json)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to export the struct fields, make them start with an uppercase letter.