# Go is Case Sensitive?

Tags: go

I'm perplexed. When I POST with the following body

```
{"lng":1.23, "lat":4.56,"utc":789}
```

This one returns {0,0,0} (incorrect)

```
func test(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
  type data struct {
    lng float64
    lat float64
    utc int
  }
  decoder := json.NewDecoder(req.Body)
  var t data
  err := decoder.Decode(&t)
  if err != nil {
      panic("PANIC")
  }
  log.Println(t)
}
```

This one returns {1.23, 4.56, 789} (correct)

```
func test(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
  type data struct {
    Lng float64
    Lat float64
    Utc int
  }
  decoder := json.NewDecoder(req.Body)
  var t data
  err := decoder.Decode(&t)
  if err != nil {
      panic("PANIC")
  }
  log.Println(t)
}
```

The only difference is that I'm using uppercase letters in my struct definition.
Am I missing something? Is this a bug?

Comment: See related questions: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327391/golang-json-marshalstruct-returns/26327436), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26050469/json-unmarshall-not-working-properly/26050501), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25595096/unmarshalling-json-golang-not-working/25595269).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [JSON encoding package](http://godoc.org/encoding/json) works with [exported fields](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers) only. The decoder is otherwise case insensitive.

You can control the case when encoding using field tags as described in the [package documentation](http://godoc.org/encoding/json).

The Go Language is case sensitive.