# Object inside slice in Go

Tags: go, slice

I am trying to embed multiple objects inside a slice, so I can later export them as JSON. The JSON should look something like this:

```
[
   {
       name: "Nginx"
       version: "1.9"
   },
   {
       name: ircd-hybrid"
       version: "8.2"
    }
]
```

So far I have this struct in Go:

```
type response struct {
    application []struct {
        name        string
        version     string
    }
}
```

Now (I'm not even sure if the struct is correct), I'm trying to access it this way (again, not sure if this is correct):

```
   var d response
   d[0].name = "Nginx"
   d[0].version = "1.9"
```

And so on and so forth. However, it is not working, so I assume I went wrong somewhere. I just don't know where.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting Go struct to JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270816/converting-go-struct-to-json)

Comment: You are not that far though, here's a simple playground code to help you http://play.golang.org/p/6IvVM3bzDU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form of your 'model' (the struct in Go in this case) isn't quite right. You really just want this;

```
type application struct {
        Name        string `json:"name"`   // gotta uppercase these so they're exported 
        Version     string `json:"version"` // otherwise you can't marshal them
    }
apps := []application{
     application{Name:"Windows", Version:"10"}
}
app := application{Name:"Linux", Vesion:"14.2"}
apps = append(apps, app)
```

The json opens with `[` meaning it is just an array, there is no enclosing object. If there were you would want another type with an application array ( `[]application` ) property. To add items to that array you can use `append` or initialize it with some instance using the 'composite literal' syntax.

EDIT: I added some annotations so the json produced will have lower cased names like in your example. If a property isn't exported in Go other libraries like `encoding/json` won't be able to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about 'uppercase', you just solved another problem of mine :-)

How can I access the slice / object? apps[0].Name gave me a "index out of range" error

Comment: @JacksGT that was the comment about append or composite literal for initilization, I'll update with an example of each.