# JSON Response in Beego Controller

Tags: json, struct, go, beego

I'm a newbie to beego trying to get a JSON response on a route.

I have a controller defined as such.

```
package controllers

import (
    "github.com/astaxie/beego"
)

type ErrorController struct {
    beego.Controller
}

type ErrorJson struct {
    s string
    d string
}

func (this *ErrorController) Get() {

    var responseJson ErrorJson
    responseJson = ErrorJson{
        s: "asdf",
        d: "qwer",
    }

    this.Data["json"] = responseJson
    this.ServeJson()
}
```

My router is defined as

```
beego.Router("/api", &controllers.ErrorController{})
```

When I visit the route, I get an Empty JSON object without any properties.

```
{}
```

If I replace the json struct with a string, I get a response. So beego is aware of the controller and the method.

```
this.Data["json"] = "Hello World"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Go json.Marshal(struct) returns "{}"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327391/go-json-marshalstruct-returns)

Comment: The same question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270816/converting-go-struct-to-json

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to [export](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers) the fields in ErrorJson by starting the name with an uppercase character. Use field tags to specify the lowercase names in the output.

```
type ErrorJson struct {
    S string `json:"s"`
    D string `json:"d"`
}
```

The encoding/json package and similar packages ignore unexported fields.

Answer (score 1):

The `s` & `d`, low case in golang is not visable.