# Api Request With Go Parse Json Response

Tags: json, api, go

Writing my first Go Application I am learning to make a basic api call and parse the json response. I am pretty sure I am not casting my types correctly and my response is

```
false
  0
 0

  0
 0 false
 0
```

If I create a few arrays with data in them I can get that response but when I add this more complexed json response to the mix things get more confusing which leads me to be quite positive I am not casting correctly.

This is my current code after playing around and changing things in order to break stuff and try and figure things out.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
) 
    type Payload struct {
        results Data 
}

    type Data struct {
        poster_path string
        adult bool
        overview string
        release_date string
        genre_ids int
        id int
        original_title string
        original_language string
        title string
        backdrop_path string
        popularity float64
        vote_count int
        video bool
        vote_average float64
}


type poster_path map[string]string
type adult map[string]bool
type overview map[string]string
type release_date map[string]string
type genre_ids map[string]int
type id map[string]int
type original_title map[string]string
type original_language map[string]string
type title map[string]string
type backdrop_path map[string]string
type popularity map[string]float64
type vote_count map[string]int
type video map[string]bool
type vote_average map[string]float64

func main() {
      // http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185
      url := "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/top_rated?api_key=####APIKEYHERE######"
      res, err := http.Get(url)
      if err != nil {
        panic(err)
      }
      defer res.Body.Close()

      body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
      if err != nil {
        panic(err)
      }
      var p Payload

      err = json.Unmarshal(body, &p)
      if err != nil {
        panic(err)
      }

      fmt.Println(
        p.results.poster_path, "\n", p.results.adult,
        p.results.overview, "\n", p.results.release_date,
        p.results.genre_ids, "\n", p.results.id,
        p.results.original_title, "\n", p.results.original_language,
        p.results.title, "\n", p.results.backdrop_path,
        p.results.popularity, "\n", p.results.vote_count,
        p.results.video, "\n", p.results.vote_average,
        )
}
```

This is what the JSON response looks like,

```
{
    "page": 1,
    "results": [
        {
            "poster_path": "/lIv1QinFqz4dlp5U4lQ6HaiskOZ.jpg",
            "adult": false,
            "overview": "Under the direction of a ruthless instructor, a talented young drummer begins to pursue perfection at any cost, even his humanity.",
            "release_date": "2014-10-10",
            "genre_ids": [
                18,
                10402
            ],
            "id": 244786,
            "original_title": "Whiplash",
            "original_language": "en",
            "title": "Whiplash",
            "backdrop_path": "/6bbZ6XyvgfjhQwbplnUh1LSj1ky.jpg",
            "popularity": 9.685051,
            "vote_count": 1706,
            "video": false,
            "vote_average": 8.36
        }
}
```

A few things that stand out to me,

When I tried to cast the float I was confused about casting from `float32` to `float64`

There is an array inside the json response which was confusing when trying to cast,

```
"genre_ids": [
                36,
                18,
                53,
                10752
            ],
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting Go struct to JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270816/converting-go-struct-to-json)

Comment: I genuinely don't mean this in a bad way, but all your `type`'s... that's just horrible. Do you really _need_ them? I mean: what's wrong with the occasional `map[string]interface{}`? You're basically declaring types that are maps, whereas (when dealing with json) a struct is just sooo much easier

Comment: Hey thank you for your feedback. I will take any criticism you may offer. This is the absolute first script I have written in Go. I watched a view tutorials and this is what I gained from them. I removed all those maps and it makes a lot more sense from Pie-o-Pah answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are missing a closing square bracket `]` at the end of `results` in your JSON.

Secondly, you did not structure your structs according to the JSON you receive.

Lastly, use JSON tags after each exported field in your struct when dealing with Unmarshal/marshaling to help Go detect the appropriate fields (not necessary if you name the fields according to [how Unmarshal/marshal identify fields](http://blog.golang.org/json-and-go).

```
type Payload struct {
        Page    int
        Results []Data 
}

type Data struct {
        PosterPath       string  `json:"poster_path"`
        Adult            bool    `json:"adult"`
        Overview         string  `json:"overview"`
        ReleaseDate      string  `json:"release_date"`
        GenreIds         []int   `json:"genre_ids"`
        Id               int     `json:"id"`
        OriginalTitle    string  `json:"original_title"`
        OriginalLanguage string  `json:"original_language"`
        Title            string  `json:"title"`
        BackdropPath     string  `json:"backdrop_path"`
        Popularity       float64 `json:"popularity"`
        VoteCount        int     `json:"vote_count"`
        Video            bool    `json:"video"`
        VoteAverage      float64 `json:"vote_average"`
}
```

Note that `GenreIds` has to be `[]int` to match the JSON data as well. And it's a good idea not to use CamelCase in Go.

See https://play.golang.org/p/VduPD9AY84

Comment: Note that you do not need struct tags: you use them when the JSON key names do not match your Go struct field names.

Comment: @elithrar thanks it's a safeguard since wuno's few original field names don't match the JSON.

Comment: I know; I'm being a pedant and saying that "always use JSON tags" is not entirely correct. It's important for the OP to know when you would use them; the real problem was the unexported struct fields.

Comment: @elithrar you are right. Edited as per your comment!

Answer (score 4):

Is a common beginners mistake. Due to language design, the `encoding/json` package can only unmarshal into *exported fields*.

From the [`encoding/json`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal) package:

> To unmarshal JSON into a struct, Unmarshal matches incoming object keys to
>   the keys used by Marshal (either the struct field name or its tag),
>   preferring an exact match but also accepting a case-insensitive match.
>   **Unmarshal will only set exported fields of the struct.**

To export a field, simply use a capital first letter of the name. Eg.:

```
type Payload struct {
    Results Data 
}
```

instead of

```
type Payload struct {
    results Data 
}
```

Comment: Hey man thank you so much. That makes sense and helped. I am almost there. Would you mind taking a look at the types vs the type in the json and make sure I am casting correctly? Because I am getting this now go run request.go
panic: json: cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type main.Data

Comment: @wuno Sure. The error is simple. `"results"` is an array of data objects (as the error says), but in Go you have defined `Results` as a simple `Data` object. Just change  `Results Data` to `Results []Data`

Comment: So funny. Right before you answered me I found something talking about this. I am sure I am not casting correctly and when I make that change I still have a bunch of this now .Results.Backdrop_path undefined (type []Data has no field or method Backdrop_path)

Comment: @wuno: No. Results doesn't have any fields. Results is a slice. But `Results[0].Backdrop_path` will work .. given the JSON object contains at least one result object in the array.

Comment: Thanks man, I really appreciate you. I can loop through the array now but its still just printing out 0 and false. for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
  fmt.Println(
    p.Results[i].poster_path, 
results in  false
  0
 0

  0
 0 false
 0

 false
  0
 0

  0
 0 fals

Comment: @wuno probably because you haven't included JSON tags to help Go to match your exported fields. See my answer it worked just fine.

Comment: @wuno Exactly like pie-o-pah says: You have to export the fields in the `Data` type as well. Eg. `poster_path` -> `Poster_path`