# JSON Decoder ignores struct field tags?

Tags: json, go, struct, config, decoding

I'm using the `Decoder` from package `encoding/json` to decode a JSON configuration file into a struct. The field names have a different case (lowercase first character in struct because of visibility concerns) in the file and struct so I'm using struct field tags as described in the [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal). The **Problem** is that `Decoder` seems to ignore these tags and the struct fields are empty. Any ideas what's wrong with my code?

### config.json

```
{
    "DataSourceName": "simple-blog.db"
}
```

### Config struct

```
type Config struct {
     dataSourceName string `json:"DataSourceName"`
}
```

### Loading config

```
func loadConfig(fileName string) {
    file, err := os.Open(fileName)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Opening config file failed: %s", err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    decoder := json.NewDecoder(file)
    config = &Config{} // Variable config is defined outside
    err = decoder.Decode(config)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Decoding config file failed: %s", err)
    }

    log.Print("Configuration successfully loaded")
}
```

### Usage

```
loadConfig("config.json")
log.Printf("DataSourceName: %s", config.dataSourceName)
```

### Output

```
2017/10/15 21:04:11 DB Name:
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting Go struct to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270816/converting-go-struct-to-json)

Comment: Duplicate, this comes up very often.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to export your `dataSourceName` field as `encoding/json` package requires them to be so

Comment: If what that means is not obvious, dataSourceName needs to start with a capital, DataSourceName

Comment: Ok, now I get it. As someone from the Java world I thought it would not be a problem if the field isn't exported (as most libraries use the Reflection API anyway).