# how to build complex go data struct

Tags: go

I have the following data struct to build and send data in it. Then convert it to json and write a file. I need an array. Its element is a map. `map["targets"]` value is an array and `map["labels"]` is another map. How to build the complex data struct?

```
[
  {
    "targets": ["10.11.150.1:7870", "10.11.150.4:7870"],
    "labels": {
      "job": "mysql"
    }
  },
  {
    "targets": ["10.11.122.11:6001", "10.11.122.15:6002"],
    "labels": {
      "job": "postgres"
    }
  }
]
```

~

Comment: Use a converter, like the online available [JSON-to-Go](https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/). And fine-tune the result to your needs.

Comment: What have you tried? Please show your code and detail what issue(s) you've run into with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your struct would look like this:

```
type Obj struct {
    Targets []string `json:"targets"`
    Labels map[string]string `json:"labels"`
}
```

Populate it:

```
obj := []Obj{
    Obj{
        Targets: []string{"10.11.150.1:7870", "10.11.150.4:7870"},
        Labels: map[string]string{
            "job": "mysql",
        },
    },
    Obj{
        Targets: []string{"10.11.122.11:6001", "10.11.122.15:6002"},
        Labels: map[string]string{
            "job": "postgres",
        },
    },
}
```

Marshal it to a string:

```
jsonBytes, err := json.Marshal(obj)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("error marshaling struct to JSON:", err)
}
```

Write it to a file:

```
if err := ioutil.WriteFile("output.json", jsonBytes, 0644); err != nil {
    log.Fatal("error writing file:", err)
}
```

Here’s everything all together:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
)

type obj struct {
    Targets []string          `json:"targets"`
    Labels  map[string]string `json:"labels"`
}

func main() {

    obj := []obj{
        obj{
            Targets: []string{"10.11.150.1:7870", "10.11.150.4:7870"},
            Labels: map[string]string{
                "job": "mysql",
            },
        },
        obj{
            Targets: []string{"10.11.122.11:6001", "10.11.122.15:6002"},
            Labels: map[string]string{
                "job": "postgres",
            },
        },
    }

    jsonBytes, err := json.Marshal(obj)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("error marshaling struct to JSON:", err)
    }

    if err := ioutil.WriteFile("output.json", jsonBytes, 0644); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("error writing file:", err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", jsonBytes)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This example can help you:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
    "io/ioutil"
)

type Object struct {
    Targets []string `json:"targets"`
    Labels  Label    `json:"labels"`
}

type Label struct {
    Job string `json:"job"`
}

type Objects []Object

func main() {
    objs := Objects{
      {
        Targets: []string{"10.11.150.1:7870", "10.11.150.4:7870"},
        Labels:  Label{Job: "mysql"},
      },
      {
        Targets: []string{"10.11.122.11:6001", "10.11.122.15:6002"},
        Labels:  Label{Job: "postgres"},
      },
    }

    bytes, err := json.Marshal(objs)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(string(bytes))

    // 0644 is the file mode: https://golang.org/pkg/os/#FileMode
    if err := ioutil.WriteFile("objs.json", bytes, 0644); err != nil {
      fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

More information: [Converting Go struct to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270816/converting-go-struct-to-json), [Go by Example: Writing Files](https://gobyexample.com/writing-files)