# Is it possible to save an entire struct to MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, go

I am trying to set up a database for my simple project. Since in MongoDB you can save any JSON file I was wondering is there an easy solution to directly save a struct to MongoDB as a json file?

Comment: yes you can save struct directly to mongodb

Comment: What have you tried? Include your code. What problems did you encounter? Be specific.

Comment: Yes, you can marshal to JSON any struct in golang and then save it to mongoDB. However you should include your code to be more specific in the issue.

Example of struct JSON marshal: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270816/converting-go-struct-to-json

The you can write it to file if there is needed to complete the task:
https://gobyexample.com/writing-files

Comment: It would also be very, very unusual to marshal a struct to JSON and store that in MongoDB. MongoDB documents are in **BSON** format, *not* JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is the sample code to store the structure type data in the Mongodb database**

**To get data as JSON format from mongodb you have json.Marshal() method in**

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "io/ioutil"

    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
)

type Person struct {
    ID int `json:"_id"`
    Age  int    `json:"Age"`
    City string `json:"city"`
}

func main() {
    clientOptions := options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017")
    client, err := mongo.Connect(context.TODO(), clientOptions)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 3*time.Second)   
    fmt.Println("Connected to MongoDB!")
    collection := client.Database("db_name").Collection("collection_name")
    byteValues, err := ioutil.ReadFile("docs.json")
    if err != nil {
          fmt.Println("ioutil.ReadFile ERROR:", err)
    } else {
          fmt.Println("ioutil.ReadFile byteValues TYPE:", reflect.TypeOf(byteValues))
          fmt.Println("byteValues:", byteValues, "n")
          fmt.Println("byteValues:", string(byteValues))
    }
    for i := range docs {
           doc := docs[i]
           fmt.Println("ndoc _id:", doc.ID)
           fmt.Println("doc Field Str:", doc.ID)
           result, insertErr := col.InsertOne(ctx, doc)
           if insertErr != nil {
                  fmt.Println("InsertOne ERROR:", insertErr)
           } else {
           fmt.Println("InsertOne() API result:", result)
      }
}
```